# Как работает SSL в мобильных приложениях?

Tags: алгоритм, ssl, шифрование, сертификат

В браузере все понятно, у него заранее есть список вшитых сертификатов `CA`, которыми он проверяет сертификат сервера... Но как происходит проверка в мобильных приложениях? Или, допустим, когда я отправляю запрос, допустим, через `BurpSuite`?

Comment: В операционной системе мобильника точно так же вшиты сертификаты

Comment: @Abyx в фаерфоксе они вшиты таки в браузер

Comment: @andreymal и в Chrome, но могут использоваться и из Windows

Comment: @Alex78191 мне буквально только что Abyx [указал на некоторую связанную с этим неточность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686719/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-ssl-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85/686769?noredirect=1#comment1012058_686769).

Comment: @D-side для обывателя, по-моему, разницы нет.

Comment: @Alex78191 так это сайт для программистов, если что :)

Comment: @D-side для создателя браузера мб важно.

Comment: @Alex78191 не только. Любой, кто валидирует ключи SSL самостоятельно (т. к. не хочет морочиться с сертификатом от известного ЦС, к примеру), может столкнуться с этой разницей.

Comment: @D-side что значит валидировать ключ?

Comment: @Alex78191 проверять, что сервер подлинный, к примеру.

Comment: @D-side так это сам браузер будет делать на основе установленного пользовательского корневого сертификата

Comment: @Alex78191 так вопрос именно о том, что происходит вне браузеров. И то, как SSL пользуется браузер, внезапно, вовсе не единственный вариант его применения.

Comment: @D-side `так вопрос именно о том, что происходит вне браузеров` зачем тогда знать как это в Chrome сделано)

Comment: @Alex78191 затем, что там используется не совсем обычная идея, которую можно использовать где-то ещё самостоятельно :)

Comment: @D-side отлично

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общие принципы SSL (а точнее, инфраструктуры ключей) продолжают работать и в контексте мобильных приложений. Набор CA (или, по-русски, ЦС – центров сертификации):

- может быть размещен в ОС (чаще всего, т. к. он используется по умолчанию [обычно]).
- может поставляться с приложением (что не такая уж редкость, см. Firefox).
- может отсутствовать вовсе, если клиент заранее знает публичный ключ сервера сам, или может попросить пользователя проверить отпечаток ключа в интерфейсе (привет, SSH!), или просто плевать хотел на безопасность (и такое бывает! `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`).

Может использоваться несколько вариантов сразу. Например, Яндекс.Браузер использует гибрид: он рассчитывает на системное хранилище, но отпечатки (хэши) сертификатов ЦСов оттуда сравнивает с известными ему *(за уточнение механизма спасибо [Abyx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177684/abyx))*. Их немного, поэтому зашить в бинарник не проблема. Таким образом ЯБ пытается предупреждать ситуации, в которых соединение пользователя компрометируется через сторонний ЦС, установленный в систему без его ведома.

---

Так что, как видите, SSL довольно хорошо гнётся под разные ситуации.
Но реально этим богатством редко пользуются.

В подавляющем большинстве случаев сервер имеет ключ, заверенный известным ЦС, а клиент имеет только пачку известных ЦС в ОС. Сервер предоставляет доказательства, указывающие через известные ЦС на подлинность своего ключа. Так клиент понимает, что это тот самый сервер.

Comment: второй пункт, к слову, есть техника ssl pinning`а

Comment: @0xFFh нет, это не она. Больше похоже на HSTS preload list, но тоже не совсем. У Firefox и ЯБ именно собственный бандл ЦС.

Comment: @Abyx спасибо, прокомментировал этот момент.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить про Android (он построен на ядре Linux), там есть папка с сертификатами `/etc/ssl`, в которой хранится список всех установленных сертификатов в системе. Мобильные приложения при установке защищенного соединения обращаются к этому списку.